# Can I catch all possible errors with one message? Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

The project I'm working on is almost ready to ship. Occasionally, I'll encounter an error that won't allow the program to continue running like an out of bounds or a memory limitation.
[These kinds of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHDLF.jpg)
 I've been fixing them as I find them, but I'm sure there are others. However, I'm leaving this position in a few days so I need the users to not encounter these.

Is there a way in Vb.net that anytime one of those errors wants to pop up, it can catch it with an message box to the user that says something like "Something really bad happened. Please restart program"?

Comment: That really is not an ideal solution.

Comment: Look up ThreadExceptionEventHandler used in conjunction with ThreadException - you'll always have exceptions that you can't anticipate, so you want these to still be brought to someone's attention (maybe you want to be nicer to your users though). Perhaps just display the nasty message in debug mode for testing.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Oh I agree, it's really not. But I don't want the user confused by phrases like "ArgumentOutOfBound Exception"

Comment: Use the answer posted by @the_lotus and use a message box: _Oh NOES! Shit just happened!_ ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a winform, you can catch the errors by handling the [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

```
AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf UIThreadException

Private Shared Sub UIThreadException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal t As ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
    ' Handle event here and show message
    ' Exception is in t.Exception        
End Sub
```

Make sure there's no error in this error handler. I don't think it'll catch exception in other threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Try statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx), which is a simple way to handle error.

Here is a simple example:

```
 Try
        'Do something
 Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error occured")
 End Try
```

Comment: That's not really what he was asking. He was asking about a general application wide handler for unhandled exceptions, and not local exception handling.

Comment: I guess this is a method for beginners whom don't want to mess with events...But good point :)